# For loop filtered without leaving blank spaces in angular table

Tags: angular, loops, populate

developers! I'm trying to populate a table with a for loop in Angular, without leaving empty spaces on the loop that doesn't commit a specific condition.

Let's say I have 2 `ngfor` nested, where the first loops over a headers array displaying them in a horizontal position, and the second would loop over an array of objects which would be filtered in the HTML, populating for every header in a vertical way those items that commit the headers specifications.

```
<ion-row>
  <ion-item *ngFor="let book of byGroup">
    <ion-col>
      <ion-label>{{book}}</ion-label>
      //looping on headers
      <ion-item *ngFor="let book1 of allBooks[0]">
        <ion-label *ngIf="book1.group==book">{{book1.title}}</ion-label>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-col>
    //An now here for each header I just loop the whole array of objects omitting 
    //those objects that don't match with the header string that in the time the loop goes over
  </ion-item>
</ion-row>
```

And the result would be something like this:
[image]

How could I set this properly without empty cells?
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: i'd recommend you try to make your model actually reflect the view you want to display rather than trying to do all this logic in template. This would involve mapping and splitting your array into the groups you want them to be in. Your app will get very messy very quickly if you keep trying to do everything in template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the two conditions `book1.title && book1.title.trim().length`.

**Final Code:**

```
<ion-row>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let book of byGroup">
        <ion-col>
            <ion-label>{{book}}</ion-label>
            //looping on headers
            <ion-item *ngFor="let book1 of allBooks[0]">
                <ion-label *ngIf="book1.group==book && book1.title && book1.title.trim().length">{{book1.title}}</ion-label>
            </ion-item>
        </ion-col>
        //An now here for each header I just loop the whole array of objects omitting 
       //those objects that don't match with the header string that in the time the loop goes over
               
    </ion-item>
</ion-row>
```

**Edit:**

[image: Result]

Hope it's working. I've got tired. Forked your project at [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-afr2pp?file=src/app/components/all-bookmarks/all-bookmarks.component.ts).

Comment: guess isn't working . Could you send a code snippet over your solution please

Comment: If you can create the scenario at Stackblitz. It would be really helpful.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/github/enriquefgf86/testx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmodals%2Fmodals.module.ts